# spring - disable all caching for static content

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, caching

how can I disable caching of the static content?

I tried to put this in my applications.properties:

```
spring.cache.type=NONE
```

This is my config:

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry
            .addResourceHandler("/**")
            .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
            .resourceChain(true).addResolver(
            new VersionResourceResolver().addContentVersionStrategy("/**"));
}
```

Still when I change something in the css file I have to reload the page with the developer console opened in order for it to show.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move all the resources out of classpath. To replace something loaded to classpath you may need something complex like own class loader etc. Try to move to a separate folder all the resources you need to change.